# Saving a tiff raster file with matplotlib.image.imsave and matplotlib.pyplot.savefig give outputs of different sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, raster, tiff

I have a numpy array of dimension (10980x10980).

When I save it using `matplotlib.image.imsave('file.tiff',data)`, `viridis` pseudo colorscheme is automatically applied to the plot. I did this, and obtained a tiff file of 480 MB.

If I save the same figure using `matplotlib.pyplot`,

```
plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig('file.tiff')
```

I obtain a file of around 1.5 MB.

The tiff info of both the files are:

1. Using `matplotlib.image.imsave`:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 10980 Image Length: 10980
  Resolution: 100, 100 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Extra Samples: 1<unassoc-alpha>
  Samples/Pixel: 4
  Rows/Strip: 10980
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

2. Using `pyplot.savefig`:

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 640 Image Length: 480
  Resolution: 100, 100 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Extra Samples: 1<unassoc-alpha>
  Samples/Pixel: 4
  Rows/Strip: 480
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

We can see that plt.savefig has reduced the dimensions to 640x480. Why was it? And how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two different operations.

`matplotlib.image.imsave('file.tiff',data)` saves the data contained in 'data' into a tiff (essentially an array that can be viewed as an image.

`plt.imshow(data); plt.colorbar(); plt.savefig('file.tiff')` is creating a matplotlib figure, showing the data stored in data and then using the default parameters (dpi etc.) to save the *figure* as a tiff. Both syntaxes are correct, it depends on what your use case is.

Answer (score 1):

As per [pyplot.savefig's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html), if the `dpi` argument is not set, it will default to using the figure's dpi value which can affect the resolution.

The documentation for `image.imsave` states that it does not affect the resolution.

Edit addressing the author's comment on my answer: DPI is simply pixels per inch. image size = |px|/dpi = 1098/10 = 109.8 inches.
10980/1 = 10980 inches, which makes the image 100x bigger.

Comment: So, I tried to give the dimensions manually,
What's the difference in using `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10980,10980),dpi=1)` and `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1098,1098),dpi=10)`?